# How to specify the data to render on y or y1 axis, based on the yAxisID in the data being provided to the line chart using react-native-charts-wrapper

Tags: react-native, chart.js, linechart, react-native-charts-wrapper

Labels rendering on y and y1 axis labels in the line chart are similar and not as per the data provided. how can I provide the **yAxisID** to the line chart getting rendered? I am using react-native-charts-wrapper to achieve the same.

The same implementation is being done in web using chart.js. Ref : https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js?activeTab=readme

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cko8l.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuUDN.png)

**Data and config
this is how I am mapping my api response to a suitable data configuration.**

```js
const chartData = {
  dataSets:
    data && data?.dataSets?.length > 0
      ? [
          ...data.dataSets.map((item: IGraphDataSet) => ({
            values: item.data,
            label: "",
            config: {
              ...dataConfig,
              mode: data,
              color: processColor(item.color),
              circleColor: processColor(item.color),
            },
          })),
        ]
      : [],
};
```

**Where datasets array looks like:**

```json
[
  {
    color: "#6AABAC",
    data: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 338.407, 338.407, 338.407, 338.407, 338.407, 338.407,
      338.407,
    ],
    label: "sample label 1",
    yAxisID: "y1",
  },
  {
    color: "#AF8E62",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    label: "sample label 2",
    yAxisID: "y",
  },
];
```

**I need to specify the data to render on y or y1 axis, based on the yAxisID of the datasets array.**

**this is how I have configured my Line chart component**

```js
<LineChart
  key={key}
  style={styles.chart}
  legend={{ enabled: true, form: "NONE" }}
  data={chartData}
  chartDescription={{ text: "" }}
  marker={markerConfig}
  xAxis={{
    ...xAxisConfig,
    position: "BOTTOM",
    valueFormatter: data?.labels,
  }}
  yAxis={yAxisConfig}
  touchEnabled={true}
  dragEnabled={true}
  dragDecelerationEnabled={true}
  dragDecelerationFrictionCoef={0.5}
/>;
```

**I have the following configurations added for chart, x and y axis**

```
export const markerConfig = {
  enabled: true,
  digits: 2,
  markerColor: processColor("grey"),
  textColor: processColor(colors.white),
  textAlign: "center",
  flexWrap: "wrap",
};

export const dataConfig = {
  lineWidth: 2,
  drawFilled: false,
  fillAlpha: 35,
  drawValues: false,
  circleRadius: 2,
  drawCircleHole: false,
};

export const xAxisConfig = {
  granularityEnabled: true,
  granularity: 1,
  textSize: 13,
  drawGridLines: true, //need to show dash lines
  gridLineWidth: 1,
  gridColor: processColor(colors.border),
  axisLineColor: processColor(colors.border),
  textColor: processColor(colors.black),
  fontFamily: fonts.regular,
  drawLabels: true,
  labelRotationAngle: -90,
  avoidFirstLastClipping: false,
};

export const yAxisConfig = {
  left: {
    granularityEnabled: true,
    granularity: 0.1,
    textSize: 13,
    textColor: processColor(colors.black),
    fontFamily: fonts.regular,
    drawLabels: true,
    drawGridLines: true,
    gridColor: processColor(colors.border),
    drawAxisLines: false,
  },
  right: {
    granularityEnabled: true,
    granularity: 0.1,
    textSize: 13,
    textColor: processColor(colors.black),
    fontFamily: fonts.regular,
    drawLabels: true,
    drawGridLines: true,
    gridColor: processColor(colors.border),
    drawAxisLines: false,
  },
};
```

**Additional**
the only difference between the data configuration of web and mobile is that of the **yAxisId**. How can we provide the same in the Line chart.
Example of how data is configured in web:

```
const getDataSet = (dataSets) => {
  return dataSets.map((item) => {
    return {
      label: item.label,
      data: item.data,
      borderColor: item.color,
      backgroundColor: item.color,
      pointRadius: 3,
      yAxisID: item.yAxisID,
    };
  });
};
```

**Specifications**
Version: react-native-charts-wrapper : 0.5.5
Platform: iOS